Why isn't there a local maximum too (constrained optimisation in $\mathbb{R}^3$)
It's perhaps a stupid question, but I'm dealing with this problem: I have to find max and or min of $f(x, y, z) = 2x^2 + y^2 - z^2$ constrained by $x+2y+z = 1$.
Now I solved the problem and I found $x = 1/7$, $y = 4/7$ and $z = -2/7$.
Geometrically, this is a cone intersected by a plane. I use Geogebra 3D to visualise the situation, and I recognised the local minimum.
But in the picture it's like if there is also a sort of local maximum that I cannot understand if it's a fake or else... Can you enlighten me please?


There seems to be something wrong with your picture.  the point you're identifying as a local minimum has $z \gt 0$, not $z = -2/7$.

The picture has the wrong dimensions. The graph of $f$ should be four-dimensional; a three-dimensional domain and an extra dimension for the function value. In this four-dimensional space, $x + 2y + z = 1$ defines a two-dimensional flat, and above it, the function traces a three-dimensional surface. Basically, you're not going to get anywhere with plotting.

@TheoBendit You're right, I just noticed I interpreted the function in a wrong way, as if I had $z = f(x, y)$. Anyway, I obtain that point and $f(1/7, 4/7, -2/7) = 14/49$. How can I understand if this is max or min? I thought of this: the point $Q = (1, 0, 0)$ belongs to the plane, and $f(1, 0, 0) = 2 > 14/49$. This is why I thought the point was a local min, but I may be wrong...

@copper.hat I'm confused twice now. The guy in the answers says it's a saddle...

@Heidegger My apologies, I made a mistake that I usually rail on folks about. The constrained cost is unbounded above and below (substitute $z=1-x-2y$ into the cost to get $(x \  y) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \ -2 & -3\end{pmatrix} (x\ y)^T+ (2 \ 4) (x \ y)^T-1$.

The point being that, a priori, one does not know if a local extreme exists.

You've found a saddle point.
To check the max/min of a constrained optimization where the restriction is actuating (causes the maximum/minimum), simplify the objective function  using the restriction (from this answer). Since $z=1-x-2y$, we can rewrite $f$ as:
$$\begin{align}f(x, y) &= 2x^2+y^2-(1-x-2y)^2\\ &= x^2-3y^2+2x+4y+4xy\end{align}$$
The hessian is then $$\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 4 \\
    4 & -6 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
which has eigenvalues $-2\pm4\sqrt{2}$ and is indefinite. The examples provided above verify that: $f(1,0,0)>f(1/7,4/7,-2/7)>f(0,0,1)$.
The contour you've graphed is for $2x^2+y^2−z^2=0$, not for all values of $f$. Since $f$ is a 3-dimensional function, you can draw a contour plot in 3D or a proper plot in 4D.
So, for example, if you draw $2x^2+y^2−z^2=1$, you will find another contour. These are some such contours for $f=−1$, $f=0$ and $f=1$:

As for why it is a saddle point, in one direction the contours no longer touch the plane once we increase the value of $f$ above 1 (above 0.28 according to your calculations), which is what causes the maximum. There is no minimum since all the contours inside the red cone(like the yellow one) intercept the plane above and below $z=0$.

while the minimum is found on turning the image a bit, and seeing that on the new line $x+2y=1$, outer contours are always present while the inner ones no longer touch after a while.

Another way to see this is to simply draw the contour for $f(x, y) = 2x^2+y^2-(1-x-2y)^2$:

You can see the saddle clearly.

edited to correct calculation of hessian within a constraint
